# Creating Aliases for OpenMP functions || Partially Disabling openMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, preprocessor-directive

Is it was possible to create pre-processor aliases for openMP names?

IE

```
#define #myParallel #pragma omp parallel for
#define #myBarrier  #pragma omp barrier
```

For the purpose of

```
#ifdef MY_LIB_DISABLE_OPENMP
#define #myParallel 
#define #myBarrier
#else
#define #myParallel #pragma omp parallel for
#define #myBarrier  #pragma omp barrier 
#endif
```

I have two libraries both utilizing openmp. The first library (parallelized) calls the functions from the second library (also parallellized) which I believe causes an exponential amount of threads. I want to be able to disable the second libraries openmp calls. (Both of these libs are mine so I may tinker).

The only other solution is copy/pasting large chunks of codes wrapped in `#ifdef #else` but that seems very inefficient/very inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenMP runtime will very unlikely creates an exponential number of threads.

A way simpler option would be to build two versions of your own library

- libfoo.so (built **without** OpenMP)
- libfoo_omp.so (built **with** OpenMP)

and link with the library that fits best.

Note `C` defines the `_OPENMP` macro when invoked with the OpenMP flags (e.g. `-fopenmp` with `GCC`), and you can use that if everything else fails.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variety of options

1. Use modern OpenMP's task based constructs (taskloop etc). They will naturally exploit nested parallelism without creating new threads, so there is no danger of oversubscription.
2. Don't set OMP_NESTED in which case apparently nested inner parallelism will be flattened (this is likely the default behaviour anyway).
3. If you must play C macro tricks, read up on [_Pragma](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl) which lets you embed pragmas in macros.